Selenium not loading full dynamic html youtube web page
I trying to load the videos page of a youtube channel and parse it to extract recent video information.
I want to avoid using the API since it has a daily usage quota. The problem I'm having is Selenium does not seem to load the full html of the webpage when printing "driver.pagesource"..
When there are 10 comments, only 3 are parsed, and the process stops.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/example')

scroll_pause_time = 2
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")
time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="more-replies"]/yt-button-shape/button/yt-touch-feedback-shape/div/div[2]')

for button in buttons:
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        button.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to click a button: {e}")

page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

driver.quit()


